# Wordpress - Hide specific posts

Tags: wordpress, plugins, posts

I am writing a wordpress plugin and I want to hide posts/pages which contain a specific string in their title.
For example, I want to hide all the posts/pages where the title contains: [something123]

show this post/page "Lorem Ipsum"
hide this post/page "Lorem Ipsum [something123]"
hide this post/page "Hello World [something123]"
show this post/page "Hello World"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme directory find loop.php

In it there should be a line like this

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

pseudocode:

```
if (get_the_title() contains "") { endwhile; }
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

You could also use a filter:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where

Although I don't feel like writing one for you =). Maybe somebody else will.